# How do I enable Mockito debug messages?

Tags: java, debugging, testing, mockito

How do I enable [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) debug messages?  In particular, I'd like print the details of methods stubbed with `when()` and every interaction with those methods.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Mockito 1.9.0 introduced listeners and now bundles a verbose logger:

So basically if you want simple and stupid logs, just do the following:

```
List mockWithLogger = mock(List.class, withSettings().verboseLogging());
```

See http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/MockSettings.html#verboseLogging() for more information

Cheers,

Comment: Can verboseLogging be set with @Mock annotated fields?

Comment: @DanielBrotherston nope, but you can initialize the field with regular `mock(type, withSettings().verboseLogging())`. It will be picked up by `InjectMocks`

Comment: where exactly this should be kept?

Answer (score 13):

Brice answer is the way to go, but another option is:

```
new org.mockito.internal.debugging.MockitoDebuggerImpl().printInvocations(mockedObject);
```

Which just prints the interactions that happened prior to that point to the given option. Is not robust enough, but does the trick and might be useful for some cases (i.e. when using mock annotations)

For Example this should work according to [MockitoSettings](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/MockSettings.html#spiedInstance%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
spiedObject = mock(ToMock.class, withSettings().spiedInstance(toMockInstance).verboseLogging())
```

Though in 1.9.5 doesn't seem to spy anything, it just mocking it.

Comment: I like your answer better - it gives more details, and the debugger really helped me.

Comment: `MockitoDebuggerImpl` is now deprecated. Instead, use: `Mockito.mockingDetails(myMock).printInvocations()`